# How can I show company Chatter Profile Photos on a Customer Portal site?

Tags: chatter

How can I display Photos from Company Chatter Profiles in a Customer Portal page?

The Url of the Photo requires a special authentication that even a logged in 
Customer Portal user does not have, so they get an error. I tried creating a trigger that would copy the image and save it into a blob, but Salesforce gives me an error, saying I can't create HTTP requests from within triggers.

I could hard code a proxy API request using the Admin login/password, but we have to change it every 72 days, and that's a crappy way to code.

I am foiled at every turn by Salesforce.

Surely there is an easy way to show Chatter Profile pictures to users within a Customer Portal. Do you have any ideas?

Many thanks-

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Chatter isn't currently available for the Customer Portal.

You'll want to check out [Chatter Communities](http://www.salesforce.com/chatter/features/communities/), which provides chatter access to portal users.

Comment: Thanks Ryan for your help- I was aware of that limitation but am hoping someone has come up with a clever workaround.

Answer (score 2):

The photo is publicly available to sites users, then when the customer portal user logs in they no longer have access to it.  Lame.